# In the javascript unable to convert string to variable

Tags: javascript, tabulator

One of my requirement in the javascript, I am trying to convert the string which is passing from the database to javascript object.

**Step1:**
String passing from the databse:

```
"validator":["required","numeric","maxLength:14","{type: amountValidate}"]
```

**Step2:** Converting to javascript object using JSON.Parse() method, output as follows:

```
validator: Array(4)
0: "required"
1: "numeric"
2: "maxLength:14"
3: "{type: amountValidate}"
length: 4
```

**Expected output is:**
In the below code amountValidate is converting into the function by tabulator js api.

```
validator:["required","numeric","maxLength:14",{
                                    type:amountValidate,                                       
                                }]
```

Since I am applying the below function to the **type:amountValidate**, it should behave as a variable and it should not be in the double quotes.

```
 var amountValidate = function(cell, value, parameters){  
                                    var regex = /^\s*-?(\d+(\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d{1,2})\s*$/ 
                                    var n = value.match(regex);                        
                                    if(n !== null){
                                        return true;
                                    }else{
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  If you open your console and type `console.log({ key: "value" })`, you will see it log value surrounded with quotes.  Those quotes are not literals in the string.  They are the browser showing you it is a string.  Versus `console.log({ key: "\"value\"" })` which does, indeed, have literal quotes as part of the string value.

Comment: sorry for confusing, I have edited the query.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that your string is not a valid JSON. Should be something like:

```
'{"validator": ["required","numeric","maxLength:14", {"type": "amountValidate"}]}'
```

There are multiple json formatters/validators online, like [this one](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), that you could use to check it.

Comment: this should be in comment not in answer.

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper why exactly? this answers the question, so it's an answer.